# \epsfig problem

Tags: graphics

I use `\epsfig` for many years with LaTeX exploiting the `\bbllx`, `\bblly`, `\bburx`, `\bbury` clip options.  This suddenly stopped working.  For example please see my ancient but frequently downloaded [https://webspace.science.uu.nl/~rutte101/Multipanel_figure.html](https://webspace.science.uu.nl/%7Erutte101/Multipanel_figure.html)
which presently does NOT work anymore.  I tried to locate `epsfig.sty` maintainer David Carlisle but did not find an email address.

Comment: contacting David is easy. Simply check the users of this site. Instead of showing some link it would be better to provide a small complete example *here* that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `epsfig.sty` only exists for compatibility with older documents and should ***not*** be loaded and used in newer documents. The deprecation has been valid for more than 20 years. Anyway, add a minimal example of code that doesn't work.

Comment: OOPS I hope somebody can remove my question.  I forgot to add -E in  dvips -E cutmultipanel -o cutresult.eps.  Yes, this trick is decades old but works flawlessly for me and others.   I hope it keeps working, no \bbllx etc in pdflatex.  My website example includes a bunch of image files so I thought specifying the link is better.  I am much impressed again with reaction speeds!

Comment: @RobRutten --- `graphicx` has `bbllx...` etc options that should cover your needs. And `graphicx` is much more powerful and actively maintained...

Comment: please don't use epsfig for any documents written after 1994. it is just for compatibility with documents written in the 1980s

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but I might be hiding

Comment: @DavidCarlisle training for "How Not to Be Seen"?

Comment: Thanks to all of you.  I wrote my beautiful macros in early 1990s I think, use graphicx for all else.  Will try to revamp to modern times (not my preference, my website is the same for 25 years already and I love latex, emacs and more for being stable).  I did find a beautiful portrait of David Carlisle, by the way.  For me all of this may vanish since oops.

Comment: @RobRutten it is stable and epsfig will work, probably essentially forever but it was written as a historic compatibility layer for the latex2.09 version back in 1994 and so while it's Ok to use it in stable documents it's not so OK to suggest that anyone uses it with current documents. it just complicates support..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My 1990 macros in the weblink above cut figures with their own axis labeling into common size for stripping and putting together in many-panel figures where panels share the same axis scales etc.  A very common problem in astronomy and I never saw another good recipe other than doing it within the programming language.  Doing it in latex makes the principal author independent of  what coauthors program.      Must I reinvent this little wheel?  Again apology for my oops - I forgot to read my own instruction in the comment on top there.  Another oops: had to cut very much here.

Comment: @RobRutten since 1994 epsfig has been a _very_ thin wrapper around `\includegraphics`  basically `\epsfig{file=zzz,other=qqq,...}` is `\includegraphics[other=qqq,...]{zzz}`  so the facilities are the same but epsfig is a bit (fractionally) slower and (more importantly) is an unnecessary confusion for new users if they see it crop up in tutorials.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - you are persistent!  I will look into that oh-so-stable ancient tutorial.   It is downloaded regularly, often from Asia.